# Cisco Firepower 4110 CLI regular expression help

Tags: cisco, cisco-firepower

We have an automation, that logs into our firewalls and lists all NAT pools and the allocated connections using the `show nat pool` command. We want to limit the output, if possible to only show 2 or maybe 3 digit+ in the show command.

I was wondering if this is possible?

Example output from `show nat pool`:

```
TCP PAT pool xx-xxx-isp-transit, address xx.xx.xx.22(xx.xx.xx.157), range 1024-65535, allocated 100
TCP PAT pool xx-xxx-isp-transit, address xx.xx.xx.24(xx.xx.xx.188), range 1-1023, allocated 0
TCP PAT pool xx-xxx-isp-transit, address xx.xx.xx.24(xx.xx.xx.188), range 1024-65535, allocated 1
TCP PAT pool xx-xxx-isp-transit, address xx.xx.xx.23(xx.xx.xx.93), range 1-1023, allocated 21908
TCP PAT pool xx-xxx-isp-transit, address xx.xx.xx.23(xx.xx.xx.93), range 1024-65535, allocated 2
TCP PAT pool xx-xxx-isp-transit, address xx.xx.xx.22(xx.xx.xx.119), range 1-1023, allocated 0
TCP PAT pool xx-xxx-isp-transit, address xx.xx.xx.22(xx.xx.xx.119), range 1024-65535, allocated 8
TCP PAT pool xx-xxx-isp-transit, address xx.xx.xx.21(xx.xx.xx.19), range 1-1023, allocated 0
TCP PAT pool xx-xxx-isp-transit, address xx.xx.xx.21(xx.xx.xx.19), range 1024-65535, allocated 3
```

I managed to remove all allocated ending on `0` like this:

`show nat pool | grep -v .*allocated.0`

Result:

```
TCP PAT pool xx-xxx-isp-transit, address xx.xx.xx.22(xx.xx.xx.157), range 1024-65535, allocated 100
TCP PAT pool xx-xxx-isp-transit, address xx.xx.xx.24(xx.xx.xx.188), range 1024-65535, allocated 1
TCP PAT pool xx-xxx-isp-transit, address xx.xx.xx.23(xx.xx.xx.93), range 1-1023, allocated 21908
TCP PAT pool xx-xxx-isp-transit, address xx.xx.xx.23(xx.xx.xx.93), range 1024-65535, allocated 2
TCP PAT pool xx-xxx-isp-transit, address xx.xx.xx.22(xx.xx.xx.119), range 1024-65535, allocated 8
TCP PAT pool xx-xxx-isp-transit, address xx.xx.xx.21(xx.xx.xx.19), range 1024-65535, allocated 3
```

I then wanted to remove those ending on 1, 2, 3 as well, but I cannot get it to work:

```
> show nat pool | grep -v .*allocated.[0-3]
ERROR: Invalid input command arguments

show nat pool | grep -v .*allocated.(0|1|2)
```

Gives no result.

```
> show version
-------------------[ XXX ]-------------------
Model                     : Cisco Firepower 4110 Threat Defense (76) Version 7.0.4 (Build 55)
UUID                      : cb5fxx...
Rules update version      : 2022-11-30-001-vrt
VDB version               : 361
----------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Have you tried *including* what you want? `show nat pool | grep .*allocated.[0-9]{3}`

Comment: @Zac67 Hey Zac, long time no see, I just tried: `> show nat pool | grep .*allocated.[0-9]{3}` and result: `ERROR: Invalid input command arguments`

Comment: Hmm - regex variants vary greatly...  Does `show nat pool | grep .*allocated.[0-9]+` work? Or `show nat pool | grep .*allocated.[0-9][0-9][0-9]`?

Comment: @Zac67 They all give `ERROR: Invalid input command arguments`. I don't think it likes the brackets for some reason.

Comment: @Zac67 If you come to chat I can show you the output there if you want to. :)

Comment: Those grep implementations often suck big time... Very simple `show nat pool | grep .*allocated....` maybe?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141142/discussion-between-zac67-and-user56700).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it seems, you cannot use classes `[0-9]` or repetitions `{3}` with that poor regex implementation - pretty much the only thing you've got left is to match for the wanted number of *any* characters behind `allocated`:

```
show nat pool | grep allocated....
```

A leading `.*` isn't really required.

Comment: Thanks again, you are a lifesaver!